# OSGI compliant jars for Google pubsub , storage and firestore - always throws classnot found exception when all three services run together

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, osgi, google-cloud-pubsub, bnd

We have application and trying to modularized the application . So keeping the separate module for google storage, pub sub and firestore. But the problem is that when we install the 3 modules, there will some issue with classnot found exception.

Comment: Please include code (e.g. maven files), error messages and a more complete description of what you are trying to do and what you have attempted.

Comment: @David, we have merged few jars where it is causing the cyclic dependency . Looks like issue is resolved for me.